# is the following the standard date/time in xml

Tags: xml

is the "2011-03-09T08:48:36.223Z" standard xsd:date type?
what does T and Z mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z is Zulu time, same as UTC. T, I think, simply stands for "time".

---

and yes, it's the xsd standard date, according to http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp at least.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's not an xsd:date, it's an xsd:dateTime. An xsd:date would omit the time part (and the "T", though it could still include the "Z").

Answer (score 0):

This date format doesn't have anything specifically to do with XML. Rather, it is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is a widely used standard date format.

The T separates the date part and time part, to avoid ambiguity.

The Z represents "Zulu time", or UTC time zone.