# Issue with formatting dates in XML file when validating against XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xsd, xml-visualizer

Here is a sample of code for formatting dates for an XML in C#:

```
Datatable dt = Data.GetMyDataTable();

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //Create XElement with date
    XElement element = new XElement("MyElement", Convert.ToDateTime(row["MyDateColumn"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
}
```

When I look at the XML file in the Visual Studio 2008 XML Visualizer while debugging the application it show the date in the correct format of "2011-09-27".

When I use the following [DecisionSoft XML Schema Validator](http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/) to validate against the XSD file, I get the following error:

> cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '20110927' is not a valid value for 'date'.

Why does the XML Visualizer in Visual Studio 2008 show the correct format and the DecisionSoft does not?  Also, how can I modify my code to fix the issue?

Comment: If you save the XML to a file you can manually check to date format. If it's in the correct format then it's a problem with DecisionSoft.

Comment: The validator is correct. This is not a valid date/time format. There is only one valid format for a date/time in XML.

Comment: @John Saunders - What is the code for the correct format?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254597/is-the-following-the-standard-date-time-in-xml

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp clearly differntiates between xsd:date and xsd:datetime. Another reference link for xsd: date would be http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html

What have you specified in your XSD?

Comment: John why not add as an answer? Don't you want the reputation?

Comment: @RashmiPandit - `xs:date` is the format specified in the XSD file